# How to use python to show a grid over my screen?

Tags: python, macos

I'm writing a (hopefully) short python script. Part of the functionality I need is 'show a grid over the screen when the user presses the set shortcut'.  I'd like the grid to look like this:

[image]

(Image from [this github repo](https://github.com/trishume/QuickMouse))

I'm struggling to make myself clear to Google.  What would be a good choice for a python library that flashed up a grid? (I don't need to be able to click while the grid is up) Ideally without changing the active window... I definately need OSX, and linux would be a nice bonus.

Comment: I'm afraid showing a click-through transparent overlay window on top of other windows is not trivial.

Comment: Not sure what you really need to do, but you could fairly simply grab the whole screen, overlay a grid on the screen capture and display the screen capture in a smaller window... if that helps.

Comment: @MarkSetchell - hmm, that would be awkward for video, but if it's reasoonably quick, then it works for my usecase... (I'd be displaying full screen....) my instinct tells me that it would be a little slow, but it's worth an experiment if there isn't an obvious elegrant solution...

Comment: @AKX if it helps, I don't need click thought while the grid is up - I just need the grid while the shortcut is held down...